Подключение fyne GO
Есть тот, кто сможет помочь в подключении этой библиотеки? Я вроде бы делаю все правильно, но выдает кучу ошибок при запуске кода с окнами и т.д.
Пробовал найти ответ через chat GРТ но результата который меня бы устроил - не достиг. Если кто согласится помочь - предоставлю все что получаю и где что находиться.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Вы выполнили все шаги, указанные в https://docs.fyne.io/started/? Установили MSYS2, добавили в MSYS2 компилятор командой pacman -S git mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain, создали пакет... Опишите, как вы устанавливали fyne.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Сначала вы должны установить сам fyne (видимо вы это уже сделали):
go get fyne.io/fyne/v2@latest

А затем установить модуль управления окнами fyne:
go get fyne.io/fyne/v2/app@latest

Ещё на винде могут быть проблемы если у вас отсутствует компилятор, или как-то так не установлен: Ошибка error: converting to execution character set: Illegal byte sequence при запуске приложения fyne
